# Autenticação pgsql via LDAP

Tags: postgresql, ldap

As autenticações de login e senha da maquina estão alocados em um servidor `ldap`, porém, gostaria de essas mesmas senhas e logins conseguissem acessar um servidor que está no `pgsql`.

Fiz a seguinte sintaxe, porém, não tive êxito.

```
host    all             all                 all                 ldap ldapserver=***.***.***-** ldapport=389 ldapprefix="OU=SMF,OU=PMC" ldapsuffix="cn=Users,dc=pmc,dc=local"
```

Preciso, usando a senha que está no servidor `ldap`, acessar um servidor do `pgsql`, lembrando que não tenho acesso a árvore do `ldap`.

Comment: A pergunta não está clara. O que você quer fazer com a função [`host`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-net.html) ela serve para converter um IP em string

Comment: Vou tentar ser mais claro, o ldap ele autentica o acesso a máquina do usuário, e já tem uma aplicação que consegue acessar sem a pessoa precisar colocar senha e login novamente pois ele já faz a autenticação no ldap, e agora, preciso criar isso para um servidor que está no pgsql, sem a pessoa precisar colocar login e senha, somente pela autenticação do ldap, não sei se isso é possivel, e eu não tenho acesso a árvore do ldap. Lembrando que essa sintaxe acima é feita dentro do arquivo pg_hba.conf.